# Let's have a presence at GDC Online in October

Tags: discussion, conferences, site-promotion

[GDC Online](http://www.gdconline.com/) is in Austin, Texas from October 10th-13th. Would you guys like GDSE to have some kind of presence there? We could do this in one of a few ways:

- Sponsoring a community member to attend the conference
- Setting up a booth at the con
- Sponsoring the con in some way - tote bag inserts, for example
- Organizing a meetup at a venue near the convention
- Something else awesome that you come up with

We have the budget to combine some of these options, but not all. So! What do you folks think would be most beneficial to our community in terms of getting the word out about how awesome we are?

(Note: this would be in addition to, not instead of, also having an awesome presence at the main GDC in San Francisco in March.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you've seen this page: http://www.jointhegamenetwork.com/event/online/generalsponsor.html

I do think tote bag inserts would be a bare minimum.  There are some other interesting sponsorship opportunities, like paying for the exhibitor mixer.

Comment: You went to GDC 2011, right? Could you shoot me an email? I'd love to chat with you about your experience with our sponsorship and stuff.